# What is a regular expression that satisfies all valid options for a JOB card in JCL?

Tags: regex, mainframe, zos, jcl

I'm working on a program that will need to remove a JOB card from a JCL member. I'm having a lot of trouble building something that satisfies all possible options and configurations.

Below is a good guide on the JOB statement:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jcl/jcl_job_statement.htm

Some issues though:

1. There may be multiple job cards in a member
2. There may be comments in the job card
3. There may be characters in columns 73-80
4. There may be a SYSAFF, SET or similar statement directly following the JOB statement that should be retained but may begin with slashes and spaces just like a job card

Any help would be appreciated. Currently I have the following regular expression:

```
//.*JOB.*\n(//\s{4,}[^\s]+(\s|\d)*\n)+
```

Ultimately I only need to change the JOB name to fit the restriction of the FTP JES reader which requires your job name to be the submitting USERID plus exactly one character under JESINTERFACELEVEL 1 which is used by our site. Changing only the job name would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to account for the two positional parameters -- 142 bytes of accounting information and 30ish bytes for programmers name.  Also, you will have to account for the optional keyword parameters:

```
ADDRSPC=   BYTES=     CARDS=      CLASS=      COND=    
GROUP=     LINES=     MEMLIMIT=   MSGCLASS=   MSGLEVEL=
NOTIFY=    PAGES=     PASSWORD=   PERFORM=    PRTY=    
RD=        REGION=    RESTART=    SECLABEL=   SCHENV=  
TIME=      TYPRUN=    USER=
```

Dealing with the JES commands like SYSAFF and other JCL commands like SET make it very complicated.

You might want to approach it in steps -- regex to handle the "//" followed by up to 69 bytes and continued with a comma except in cases of comments where it starts with "//*".

It might help to know what you are trying to accomplish.  You can ask JES to process the JCL for you and there are ways you can inspect the parsed JCL via macros, exits and control blocks.

Comment: Hello Joe, thanks for the input. I'm trying to pull off the job cards to change the job names so they can be submitted to JES through FTP with a JESINTERFACELEVEL of 1 requiring the job names to be the user's ID plus exactly 1 character. It might just be best to find the JOB card and change the job name only instead of the whole thing.

Comment: @Burke9077 can you add that information into the question please?

Comment: If that is all you want to do, and accounting information can stay unchanged, then you should scan for <beginning of member OR "//"> followed by a line with "//<1-8 chars><blanks>'JOB'<blanks><anything> and do your replacement on the <1-8 chars> and you will be fine.  As Bill said, be careful of instream JCL using the DATA/DLM= stuff, unless you want to change those job cards too, in which case, treat the first line of data as beginning of file or after a "//".

Answer (score 2):

With the information from your comment on Joe's answer, your task becomes easier.

```
 //JJJJJAAA JOB other-stuff
```

If the second word is `JOB` and the first two characters of the first word are `//` and the third character is not `*`, then you have a JOB card. Remove the first word, replacing it with `//JJJJJx`, where `x` is your additional single character. JJJJJ represents the user-id.

This does assume that the user-id of the existing JOBs will be the same as the user-id of the new JOBs, in which case the replacement JOB name is not going to cause the extension of the JOB card.

If this is not the case, if the user-id on the original JOB cards is shorter, or indeed not a user-id at all and is shorter, either all or some, then I'd recommend splitting the JOB card after the first comma (if present).

In the unlikely event that you have very long accounting information and nothing else, this may cause a JCL error when the above is true. If so, fix the accounting information or get around the user-id limit. This is an unlikely situation :-)

If there is no accounting information but there is a long comment, this may cause a JCL error by accidentally hitting column 72 with data (so it will think the next line is a Continuation). In the unlikely even of that happening, fix it.

Neither of these two are worth coding for. They are worth verifying for, though the simplest way to do that is to watch and pick them up if they fall over.

You do have one more thing to watch for, and this is whether any of your steps use `DD *` or `DD DATA`. If they do, then you have to discover if any use `DLM=`. If they do, you will have to switch off the search for the JOB card when encountering `DLM=`, and switch it on again when you reach the delimiter value starting in column one.

Your single character may cause you problems. You will have a limited number of jobnames possible per userid. Unless allowed, JOBs with the same name will not run at the same time.

Comment: one very unlikely error is you could make the Job line to long, i.e. if you replace //j1 job with //myjob001 job; the line might end up being > 71 chars

Comment: Yes @BruceMartin, I meant to imply (and should have said) that because the replacement would be user-id plus one in length, this would *likely* be shorter than or equal to the existing jobname. I blew the implication by using JJJJJ and then later userid (how did I ever type that in lowercase?).

Comment: De nada.  DLM= is an interesting edge case and I'm glad you added it to this thread.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I really appreciate your input. These jobs will be run by an individual doing DB2 maintenance so they will need to be single threaded anyway. Thanks for bringing up the DLM case, I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's the first card anyway. Or at least the first non-comment card.

Comment: `There may be multiple job cards in a member` states OP.